# AdView requests new add every time SeekBar is touched

Tags: android, admob, live-wallpaper

I am creating a live wallpaper settings activity. It has a few seek bars and an Ad Mob ad view. Every time I touch one of the seek bars the ad temporarily disappears and then reloads a new add. However, the ad does not change when any of the other preferences are touched. How do I stop the ad from reloading when a seek bar preference is touched? I am pretty stumped on this one :-). Code follows:

The ad preference class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class AdPreference extends Preference {

    public AdPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super    (context, attrs, defStyle);}
    public AdPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}
    public AdPreference(Context context) {super(context);}

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        // this will create the linear layout defined in ads_layout.xml
        View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

        // the context is a PreferenceActivity
        Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();

        // Create the adView
        AdView adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, "a151390e12917b5");

        ((LinearLayout)view).addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.addTestDevice("23392C83B8B55DE893A18286CB92DDA2");
        request.addTestDevice("E1BAA0317138AEE05268B2E4F76B2D3F");
        adView.loadAd(request);     

        return view;    
    }
}
```

The seek bar class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SeekBarPreference extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    private static final String ANDROIDNS="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    private static final String ROBOBUNNYNS="http://robobunny.com";
    private static final int DEFAULT_VALUE = 50;

    private int mMaxValue      = 100;
    private int mMinValue      = 0;
    private int mInterval      = 1;
    private int mCurrentValue;
    private String mUnitsLeft  = "";
    private String mUnitsRight = "";
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;

    private TextView mStatusText;

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initPreference(context, attrs);
    }

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initPreference(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setValuesFromXml(attrs);
        mSeekBar = new SeekBar(context, attrs);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mMaxValue - mMinValue);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void setValuesFromXml(AttributeSet attrs) {
        mMaxValue = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROIDNS, "max", 100);
        mMinValue = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ROBOBUNNYNS, "min", 0);

        mUnitsLeft = getAttributeStringValue(attrs, ROBOBUNNYNS, "unitsLeft", "");
        String units = getAttributeStringValue(attrs, ROBOBUNNYNS, "units", "");
        mUnitsRight = getAttributeStringValue(attrs, ROBOBUNNYNS, "unitsRight", units);

        try {
            String newInterval = attrs.getAttributeValue(ROBOBUNNYNS, "interval");
            if(newInterval != null)
                mInterval = Integer.parseInt(newInterval);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid interval value", e);
        }

    }

    private String getAttributeStringValue(AttributeSet attrs, String namespace, String name, String defaultValue) {
        String value = attrs.getAttributeValue(namespace, name);
        if(value == null)
            value = defaultValue;

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent){

        RelativeLayout layout =  null;

        try {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            layout = (RelativeLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.seek_bar_preference, parent, false);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating seek bar preference", e);
        }

        return layout;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);

        try
        {
            // move our seekbar to the new view we've been given
            ViewParent oldContainer = mSeekBar.getParent();
            ViewGroup newContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefBarContainer);

            if (oldContainer != newContainer) {
                // remove the seekbar from the old view
                if (oldContainer != null) {
                    ((ViewGroup) oldContainer).removeView(mSeekBar);
                }
                // remove the existing seekbar (there may not be one) and add ours
                newContainer.removeAllViews();
                newContainer.addView(mSeekBar, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error binding view: " + ex.toString());
        }

        updateView(view);
    }

    /**
     * Update a SeekBarPreference view with our current state
     * @param view
     */
    protected void updateView(View view) {

        try {
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)view;

            mStatusText = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefValue);
            mStatusText.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentValue));
            mStatusText.setMinimumWidth(30);

            mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentValue - mMinValue);

            TextView unitsRight = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefUnitsRight);
            unitsRight.setText(mUnitsRight);

            TextView unitsLeft = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefUnitsLeft);
            unitsLeft.setText(mUnitsLeft);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error updating seek bar preference", e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        int newValue = progress + mMinValue;

        if(newValue > mMaxValue)
            newValue = mMaxValue;
        else if(newValue < mMinValue)
            newValue = mMinValue;
        else if(mInterval != 1 && newValue % mInterval != 0)
            newValue = Math.round(((float)newValue)/mInterval)*mInterval;  

        // change rejected, revert to the previous value
        if(!callChangeListener(newValue)){
            seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentValue - mMinValue); 
            return; 
        }

        // change accepted, store it
        mCurrentValue = newValue;
        mStatusText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
        persistInt(newValue);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        notifyChanged();
    }


    @Override 
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray ta, int index){

        int defaultValue = ta.getInt(index, DEFAULT_VALUE);
        return defaultValue;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {

        if(restoreValue) {
            mCurrentValue = getPersistedInt(mCurrentValue);
        }
        else {
            int temp = 0;
            try {
                temp = (Integer)defaultValue;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid default value: " + defaultValue.toString());
            }

            persistInt(temp);
            mCurrentValue = temp;
        }

    }

}
```

The xml layout for the settings activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:robobunny="http://robobunny.com"
    android:key="disco_wormhole_settings" >

    <com.package.name.and.AdPreference
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        androidLlayout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Preference
        android:key="title"
        android:summary="@string/settings_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_title" />

    <com.package.name.and.SeekBarPreference
        android:defaultValue="50"
        android:key="flight_speed"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress"
        android:summary="@string/flight_speed_summary"
        android:title="@string/flight_speed_title"
        robobunny:min="1"
        robobunny:unitsLeft=""
        robobunny:unitsRight="%" />
    <com.package.name.and.SeekBarPreference
        android:defaultValue="30"
        android:key="num_rings"
        android:max="40"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress"
        android:summary="@string/num_rings_summary"
        android:title="@string/num_rings_title"
        robobunny:min="1"
        robobunny:unitsLeft=""
        robobunny:unitsRight="" />
    <com.package.name.and.SeekBarPreference
        android:defaultValue="50"
        android:key="particle_speed"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress"
        android:summary="@string/particle_speed_summary"
        android:title="@string/particle_speed_title"
        robobunny:min="1"
        robobunny:unitsLeft=""
        robobunny:unitsRight="%" />

    <Preference
        android:summary="@string/colors_summary"
        android:title="@string/colors_title" >
    </Preference>
    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="0xff7d9fff"
        android:key="color_one"
        android:title="@string/color_one" >
    </Preference>
    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="0xffff4b31"
        android:key="color_two"
        android:title="@string/color_two" >
    </Preference>
    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="0xff64ff46"
        android:key="color_three"
        android:title="@string/color_three" >
    </Preference>

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="use_space_dust"
        android:title="@string/use_space_dust_title" />

    <Preference
        android:key="spacer"
        android:title="@string/single_space" />
    <Preference>
    </Preference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think onCreateView will be called multiple times so an ad request will be created every time. Try moving your admob code to something like onBind or onAttached.

Comment: You are right. onCreateView is called every time the seek bar preference is touched (WAT?). I moved my add request code to onAttachedToActivity. I also only add the view to the parent once in onCreateView via a null check.